# Solving the Mystery: How to fix "This action requires merchant approval for read_checkouts scope" Error on Shopify REST Admin API GET Request

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm going through a weird error when making a simple GET request using the Shopify REST Admin API. When I query with a GET request `{store_url}/admin/checkouts.json` I can get all the checkouts. Now, when I query `admin/api/2023-01/checkouts/<checkout_token>`.json I get this error `{ "errors": "[API] This action requires merchant approval for read_checkouts scope." }`

I'm using the same store, same key. Its access scope is read_orders, a custom/private app.

Any clue?

I tried swapping using the checkout id, checkout token, checkout key. I also tried calling the orders endpoint using the checkout token and id. No luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your App does not have the needed scope ***read_checkouts***

If you add that scope to the App your call to the checkout endpoint will work.